# How to identify computer through usb device?

Tags: usb, arduino

Is it possible to identify to which pc usb device is connected inside usb device?

Dose computers send any identification information to usb device when you connect usb device to the computer?

Assume, I have 5 computers and usb arduino, I want to know inside arduino to which of this 5 computer I am connected.

For example, I have 5 led on arduino, when I connect arduino to the first computer, first led lights up, when I connect to the second computer, second led lights up, and so on...

Is that possible to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not unless the computer runs a **custom** program or driver that deliberately sends this information in whichever format you've decided.